# Java- Null handling

Tags: java, error-handling, null

I have a array that can sometimes be `null (strings[0])` and I want to be able to detect when its null so I don't get a error and I can tell the user.

I tried a if statement

```
(if (strings == null){
   //do my code
})
```

that didn't work. I tried to do `try, catch (NullPointerException)` but I'm getting an error in my IDE. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out my answer. It will show you each index that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check:

```
if(array != null && array.length !=0){
    //relevant code
}else{
    //relevant code
}
```

This helps if the array is not `null` and is not empty.

Comment: I was going to say that! :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `array.length` instead of `array.size()`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it didn't work but it seems like it should. At this point I am starting to think that the error is coming from somewhere else. Ah code, always seeming like it should work even though it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry yes. It should be array.length. Thanks for the edit. Couldn't format properly since I'm on mobile :-)

Comment: @NatServ: What is the error? You can edit your answer and paste the whole code so that we can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strings == null)
```

returns true if strings **is** null

what you want is:

```
if (strings != null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but strings == null is what I want, it just wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your `strings` array and checking for the null objects like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if (strings[i] == null) {
        System.out.println("The item at index [" + i + "] is null!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what others have stated earlier

```
if (strings == null)
    //code here
```

This pattern works great. A point to remember if you want to combine conditionals using the short circuit &&, || operators.

These two logical operators stop when the boolean value can be determined.

so if we have

```
if (strings == null && someFunction() == anotherFunction())
```

in the case that strings is null

```
someFunction() == anotherFunction() //<- this would not be evaluated.
```

because false && anyotherBool will never be true